# Cloud-watch billing how to find which service or metrics are generating bills?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-billing

My cloudwatch bill has a $400 spike from August to September.
$0.01 per 1,000 requests(blended rate: 0.000010)161,204,177 Requests
$0.01 per 1,000 requests(blended rate: 0.000010)206,899,565 Requests

how can we check why requests have increased so much and determine their end points
or where the requests are coming from

Answer (score 9):

This is likely a monitoring tool, DataDog is one example, but any tool that queries AWS continually to get stats on all of your servers. Are you importing your data to any third party tools, or internally built tools?

CloudTrail does NOT log this request, per the answer below from AWS to a similar question - This would be my answer too in general, this is a special case :-(

"Unfortunately, there is no tool from your side to check the source of GetMetricData. The reason being, this API call is not logged in CloudTrail." -- akash-aws from forums

Additional Info: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=865061

Good luck finding the cause, I'm looking into a similar problem for a client and tracked down when it started, now to hopefully find more details.

Answer (score 2):

See if you're getting billed for GetMetricData requests. If yes, see if you're running any 3rd party monitoring solutions that get metrics from your AWS account. Finally, to confirm it's caused by the 3rd party monitoring tool, turn off the tool if you're allowed to, at least for an hour or so, to see if there's indeed a dent in your bill at that hour.

I wrote detailed steps here: https://ystoneman.medium.com/a-hidden-cost-to-monitoring-aws-with-3rd-party-tools-e23dd9e38c75

Answer (score -3):

You can [Log Amazon CloudWatch API Calls with AWS CloudTrail - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/logging_cw_api_calls.html):

> Amazon CloudWatch is integrated with AWS CloudTrail, a service that provides a record of actions taken by a user, role, or an AWS service in CloudWatch. CloudTrail captures API calls made by or on behalf of your AWS account. The calls captured include calls from the CloudWatch console and code calls to the CloudWatch API operations.
>
> If you create a trail, you can enable continuous delivery of CloudTrail events to an Amazon S3 bucket, including events for CloudWatch. If you don't configure a trail, you can still view the most recent events in the CloudTrail console in **Event history**.
>
> Using the information collected by CloudTrail, you can determine the request that was made to CloudWatch, the IP address from which the request was made, who made the request, when it was made, and additional details.

Comment: CloudTrail doesn't log this request :-( It sure seems like it should to me.